# Get ranges of True values (start and end) in a boolean list (without using a for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example I want to convert this list

```
x=[False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

to a ranges (start and end locations) of `True` values

```
[[1,4],
 [6,7],
 [9,9]]
```

This is obviously possible using a `for` loop. However, I am looking for a other options that are faster and better (one-liners are welcome e.g. maybe a list comprehension). Ideally, I am looking for some way that could also be applicable to a `pandas` series.

Comment: Using a `for` loop is O(n) and it's impossible to do it faster. Other solutions that might require specific containers/data structures would take at least O(n) to construct.

Comment: I believe the last one should be [9,9].

Comment: Ok. So, what is 'O(n)'?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Ramirez The time complexity of the potential algorithm, denoting how it will scale with the size of input. Here the best you will get(using a for loop) scales linearly with the size of your input; i.e. `len(x)`

Comment: This is a very basic operation. I wonder if there is any function in basic libraries (e.g. `numpy`) that does this conversion rightaway. Also, a function that does the reverse conversion would be great to know.

Comment: @BTables The phrase *without using for loops* in numpy and pandas questions generally means *without using an explicit Python loop but instead calling a wrapper to an optimized function written in C* as that's the fundamental approach of these libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `Pandas` only:

```
s = pd.Series(x)
grp = s.eq(False).cumsum()
arr = grp.loc[s.eq(True)] \
         .groupby(grp) \
         .apply(lambda x: [x.index.min(), x.index.max()])
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
1    [1, 4]
2    [6, 7]
3    [9, 9]
dtype: object

>>> arr.tolist()
[[1, 4], [6, 7], [9, 9]]
```

Alternative:

```
np.vstack([s[s & (s.shift(1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values, 
           s[s & (s.shift(-1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values]).T

# Output:
array([[1, 4],
       [6, 7],
       [9, 9]])
```

**Performance**

```
# Solution 1
>>> %timeit s.eq(False).cumsum().loc[s.eq(True)].groupby(s.eq(False).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: [x.index.min(), x.index.max()])
1.22 ms ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Solution 2
>>> %timeit np.vstack([s[s & (s.shift(1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values, s[s & (s.shift(-1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values]).T
477 µs ± 5.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Solution @psidom
>>> %timeit np_vec2ran(x)
29.2 µs ± 3.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For 1,000,000 records:

```
x = np.random.choice([True, False], 1000000)
s = pd.Series(s)

>>> %timeit np.vstack([s[s & (s.shift(1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values, s[s & (s.shift(-1, fill_value=False) == False)].index.values]).T
18.2 ms ± 247 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit np_vec2ran(x)
5.03 ms ± 266 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: ~1.65 times faster (1.58ms) than my solution that uses `scipy` in addition to `pandas` (2.61ms). Nice!

Comment: 980 µs for the alternative answer! very cool!

Comment: The alternative answer gives incorrect output for `x=[True,False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True]` though.

Comment: I fixed my alternative solution. Now the output should be consistent.

Comment: Btw, I hope it is not test in len(x)=10 ? Why not x=1000 ? Performance should be different like in small data

Answer (score 3):

Option with `numpy`. We can check if previous value is False and current value is True, then it's the start of True sequence. On the other hand, if previous value is True and current value is False, then it's the end of True sequence.

```
z = np.concatenate(([False], x, [False]))

start = np.flatnonzero(~z[:-1] & z[1:])   
end = np.flatnonzero(z[:-1] & ~z[1:])

np.column_stack((start, end-1))
array([[1, 4],
       [6, 7],
       [9, 9]], dtype=int32)
```

A little benchmark against the faster pandas solution:

```
def np_vec2ran(x):
    z = np.concatenate(([False], x, [False]))

    start = np.flatnonzero(~z[:-1] & z[1:])
    end = np.flatnonzero(z[:-1] & ~z[1:])

    return np.column_stack((start, end-1))

np_vec2ran(x)
array([[1, 4],
       [6, 7],
       [9, 9]], dtype=int32)

def pd_vec2ran(x):
    s = pd.Series(x)
    return list(zip(s[s.eq(True) & s.shift(1).eq(False)].index, s[s.eq(True) & s.shift(-1, fill_value=False).eq(False)].index))

pd_vec2ran(x)
[(1, 4), (6, 7), (9, 9)]

timeit('pd_vec2ran(x)', number=10, globals=globals())
0.040585001000181364

timeit('np_vec2ran(x)', number=10, globals=globals())
0.0011799999992945231
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `scipy` and `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
def boolean_vector2ranges(x):
    df1=pd.DataFrame({'location':range(len(l)),
                      'bool':x,
                     })
    df1['group']=sc.ndimage.measurements.label(df1['bool'].astype(int))[0]
    return df1.loc[(df1['group']!=0),:].groupby('group')['location'].agg([min,max])

boolean_vector2ranges(x=[False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True])
```

returns,

[image]