# A boolean list from ranges of True values (start and end), without using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example I have this list containing ranges.

```
x=[[1,4],
   [6,7],
   [9,9]]
```

where the first value of each item (e.g. `[1,4]`) is the start position (`1`) and, the second value is the end (`4`) position.

I want to convert this list of ranges into a boolean list, wherein the value is `True` if the position is between (any of) the ranges (i.e. the start and end positions) indicated in the list above, otherwise the value should be `False`.

```
[False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

This is obviously possible using a for loop. However, I am looking for a other options that are one-liners. Ideally, I am looking for some way that could also be applicable to a pandas series.

Note: This is essentially an opposite problem of this question: [Get ranges of True values (start and end) in a boolean list (without using a for loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457696/)

Comment: What's the logic for determining what is mapped to `True`? Why does your boolean list have ten items when the original has six?

Comment: @ddejohn I agree it's not well formatted or explained, but I guess the logic is similar to this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69457696/10237506)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hopefully efficient way using numpy:

```
low, high = np.array(x).T[:,:, None] # rearrange the limits into a 3d array in a convenient shape
a = np.arange(high.max() + 1) # make a range from 0 to 9
print(((a >= low) & (a <= high)).any(axis=0))
```

An alternative that edits the array in a python loop:

```
result = np.zeros(np.array(x).max() + 1, dtype=bool)
for start, end in x:
    result[start:end+1] = True
```

This could be faster depending on the speed of editing a slice of an array relative to numpy 2d matrix comparisons.

Comment: What's the complexity? I think O(max(high) * len(high)), so rather quadratic?

Comment: Perhaps someone who is an expert on big O complexity of matrix maths can comment. It's efficient in the sense that it delegates all the work to numpy's vector functions written in well-optimized C, avoiding any python loops. There could be a better solution if the ranges are sorted first, or assumed to be already sorted.

Comment: I don't think we need an "expert" :-). Your `a >= low` is a 2D array with width max(high) and height len(high), right? And the time is surely linear in the size of that. Same for the other operations in that line of code.

Comment: While a loop solution would take only O(max(high)).